# Choosing a multiplier for a (string) hash function

Tags: performance, algorithm

Do you have any advice/rules on selecting a multiplier to use in a (multiplicative) hash function. The function is computing the hash value of a string.

Comment: The following page has several implementations of general purpose hash functions that are efficient and exhibit minimal collisions: http://partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use something that is relatively prime to the size of your set. That way, when you loop around, you won't end up on the same numbers you just tried.

Answer (score 1):

Historically 33 seems like a popular choice, and it tends to work pretty well. No one knows why though. For more details, [look here](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html)

Comment: No one knows because no one tests. Praise be to magic numbers. **33** was popular because it was copied without question since 1981. **129** happens to be better, resulting in fewer collisions, and **265** is significantly better than that. FNV1a uses **16777619**, which is even better still. The larger the multiplier, the better, they just have to be odd.

Answer (score 1):

I had an interesting discussion with a coworker about hash function recently.  Our conclusions were as follows:

If you really need to write a good hash function that minimizes collisions more than the default implementations available in the standard languages you need an advanced degree in mathematics.

If you're writing applications where a custom hash function will noticeably improve the performance of your application, you're Google and you've got plenty of Math PhDs to do the work.

Sorry to not directly answer your question, but the bottom line is that there's really no need to write your own hash function for String.  What language are you working with?  I'd imagine there's an easy way to compute a "good enough" hash code.

Comment: You don't need a PhD mathematics to see a clear trend that larger multipliers result in more dispersed results and fewer collisions. You merely need to be open to understanding and be willing to write tests. Java's `hashCode()` uses a multiplier of 31 using `h = (h<<5) - h + k[i]`. A simple change to `h = (h<<7) + h + k[i]` (which is `h *= 129` instead of 31) has measurably lower collisions, merely due to the multiplier being larger. And 64-bit multipliers would improve by orders of magnitudes further. By trusting without question, we fall victim to ignorance, like `Math.random()` in JS.